# After switching from first fragment to second fragment, the bottom tab icon still shows first icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, bottomnavigationview

When the user has selected a contact, I am switching from the first fragment to the second fragment.  My app switches to the second fragment, but the tab icon still shows the first fragment as selected.

This is the code I am using to switch to my second fragment.

`Fragment fragment = new ItemSecondFragment();`    `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Where **R.id.content_frame** is my frame layout.

How can I fix the above issue?

Comment: Please show your complete code..with xml

Comment: TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex);
tab.select();

Comment: Follow this link to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501873/traversing-from-fragment-to-fragment-bottomnavigationview-icon-highlight)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will probably need to add the xml and a bit more of your code, if you wish to get further aid or help with your question.  I reformatted and fixed the grammar to flow better in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following code to set the tab icon when switching one fragment to another fragment

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);


View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.tab_calls);
view.performClick();
```

where **R.id.tab_calls** is my second fragment.

Answer (score 0):

make your bottom tabbar public static in your activity and go to second fragment by bottom bar switcher like this    @Override

```
public static BottomBar mBottomBar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

}

and in your fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MainActivity.mBottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(2);
```

}

Comment: But i am using BottomNavigation Bar.

Comment: try this if it is BottomNavigationView  setSelectedItemId(int itemId)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.tab_home:
                    fragment= TabOne.newInstance();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.tab_email:
                    fragment= TabTwo.newInstance();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.tab_members:
                    fragment= TabThree.newInstance();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.tab_link:
                    fragment= TabFour.newInstance();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    break;
            }
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
            return false;
        }

    };`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this method :

```
View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_button_two);
view.performClick();
```