# Change container page onClick a menu item

Tags: android, android-layout

how to change the tabs `container` on click `Home` item?

**bottom_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp"
        android:title="Status"
        android:onClick="go_page('Stat')"/>
</menu>
```

**From tabs.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/greyish"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>
```

**tabs.java**

```
public void go_page(String fragmentId) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentId);
        if (fragment == null) {
            if (fragmentId.equals("Stat")) {
                fragment = StatTab.newInstance();
            }
            if (fragmentId.equals("Other")) {
                fragment = OtherTab.newInstance();
            }
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentId).commit();
        }
    }
```

**StatTab fragment:**

```
public class StatTab extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stat_tab, container, false);
    }
}
```

> Cannot resolves name `newInstance()`

thank you for any help

Comment: You do not have a `static` method `newInstance()` declared in `StatTab.java`. What do you expect to happen you you do not have such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to craete  `newInstance()` method in your `StatTab`and `OtherTab` `fragment` like below code

```
 public class StatTab extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stat_tab, container, false);
        }

        public  static StatTab newInstance() {
        return new StatTab();
      }
    }


 public class OtherTab extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_other_tab, container, false);
        }

        public static OtherTab newInstance() {
        return new OtherTab();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Something wrong on adding onClick in xml file `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`

Comment: @user3449848 didn't get u

Comment: I can't implement `android:onClick="go_page('Stat')"` from `bottom_menu.xml` for `public void go_page(String fragmentId)`. Any other alternative way to do it?

Comment: @user3449848 remove `android:onClick="go_page('Stat')"` from menu.xml

Comment: @user3449848 this will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview

Comment: Got it. Can you tell me how to call this function if I remove it? Something like `OnClickListener`? Or can you refer me a tutorial where `Tablayout`and `BottomNavigationView` implemented together?

Comment: @user3449848 in that link the information give please check aghain