# Return to the main activity

Tags: java, android

I have the following question: when I return from one activity to another, I need certain element of menu to be opened. For example:

[image]

Now, when I click "Up" in my activity the first element of menu is always opened (where the running man is drawed). And I need to make such element opened, which was opened before opening new activity. For example I choose an article in Articles menu element and after clicking Up in new activity I want to be opened Articles element again. I tried to realize it as clicking on Back button:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

But it didn't help. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to keep the selected item and after returning manually select it.
See the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43117486/7469860

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to set value in BottomNavigationView from another activity, where there's no BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file, search for your Activity node and add the following line:

`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

This will define how your activity will be launched.

Here is an official documentation about `launchMode` property https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I tried to add it to first activity, second, both, but it didn't help