# How to set icon default selection on bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-bar

I am writing an Android app in Java, I refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb8SgfI4Cm4) to make a bottom navigation bar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqqA9.png)

As shown in the picture, when I switch to the activity that includes the bottom navigation bar, the fragment displays at home, but the icon is still displayed in the message. How can I make my icon default at Home?

This is my activity which includes the bottom navigation bar:

```java
package com.example.a1221_test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.a1221_test.databinding.ActivitySecondBinding;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivitySecondBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        replaceFragment(new c_HomeFragment());

        binding.bottomNavigationView2.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.home:
                    replaceFragment(new c_HomeFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.message:
                    replaceFragment(new a_MessageFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.food:
                    replaceFragment(new b_FoodFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.closet:
                    replaceFragment(new d_ClosetFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.question:
                    replaceFragment(new e_QuestionFragment());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This is my layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e8cfa6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Here is answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this, below `replaceFragment`

```
replaceFragment(new c_HomeFragment());

binding.bottomNavigationView2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setChecked(true);
```